# Passing JSON-Objekt to MYSQL columns via node

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

Currently Im trying to fill a MySQL Database with node.
The data is stored in an Object like that for example :

insertObj :

```
{"textField":"testabc","checkBox":false,"dropDown":"1"}
```

My SQL Query :

```
"INSERT INTO nodetest (textField,checkBox,dropDown) VALUES('"+insertObj.textField+"','"+insertObj.checkBox*1+"','"+insertObj.dropDown+"')"
```

Basically I just want to pass over that Object and make the database fills the right columns with the right information from the object itself.

Unfortunately I can't use any other database except MySQL but mongoDB allows something like that :

```
dbo.collection("nodeTest").insertOne(insertObj, function(err,res) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("document inserted");
            db.close();
        })
```

Is it possible to achieve something like that with a MySql database? Mabye via scripting?

Comment: Do you use a MySQL ORM ? I can advise you https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/getting-started.html) ORM . HERE are the steps to achieve your result

1.Install sequelize

```
npm install --save sequelize
```

2.Install Mysql Dialect

```
npm install --save mariadb or npm install --save mysql2 depending on your server
```

3.Setting up a connection

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', 
{
host: 'localhost',
  dialect: // one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql'
});
```

You can test the connection as:

```
sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');}).catch(err => {
console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);});
```

4.Model your table

```
const Model = Sequelize.Model;
class Classname extends Model {}
Classname.init({
textField: {
type: Sequelize.STRING,
allowNull: false},
checkBox: {
type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
// allowNull defaults to true
},dropDown: {
type: Sequelize.STRING
// allowNull defaults to true
}}, 
{sequelize,modelName: 'modelname'
});
```

5.Then you can do

```
Classname.create({"textField":"testabc","checkBox":false,"dropDown":"1"}).then(data => {
console.log(data);
});
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Shiroyashaxdd does it solve your problem?If you specifically wanna go with native mongo library then you can create a helper module to covert json into mysql fields.But ORM is most preferred,secure and recommended approach.